# What value is screen.width if there is no screen? e.g. bots

Tags: javascript, screen, conditional-statements

I've got a conditional if statement that should detect if the client has a screen dimension (as opposed to a bot) but always seems to return true:

```
var screenWidth = screen.width,
    screenHeight = screen.height; // Used elsewhere

if (screenWidth >= 1) {

    // Collate screen size

} else {

    // Do other stuff

}
```

As I say, the snippet above **always returns true** and the 'Collate screen size' code is run.

I've tried

```
if (screenWidth) { ...
if (screenWidth != null) { ...
if (screenWidth != '') { ...
if (screenWidth === '') { ...
if (typeof screen === 'object') { ...
if (typeof screenWidth === 'number') { ...
```

All with no success.

Yet in my text file (old school I know) I'm getting the following:

```
1385466873 |   |  x  |  |
                ^
```

Which makes me think the value assigned to the variable is empty!?

For reference, I get the following for 'real' browsers:

```
1385465703 | Mac OS X 10.8.4 | 1440 x 900 | undefined | MacIntel
                               ^^^^
```

See more here: http://browsertrend.info/client.txt

---

**More info:**

Having added the screen.width typeof to the output I now get:

```
1385485905 | Windows 7 | number | 1200 x 1600 | undefined | Win32
                         ^^^^^^
```

And nothing, as below:

```
1385485903 |   |  |  x  |  | 
                ^
```

So surely testing for:

```
if (typeof screenWidth === 'number') { ...
```

should have worked?

---

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you create the text file? What code do you use to build `1385466873||x||`?

Comment: That's all done in the first part of the condition (The 'collate screen size' part') - the JS script fires off the data to a PHP script on my server.

Comment: I still don't see the code that you use.

Comment: Do you really think it's relevant? All that is inside the condition that doesn't work...

Comment: For a better idea of what is being output see: http://browsertrend.info/client.txt - the lines where no screen dimensions appear are the clients I want to filter out in the condition in the question.

Comment: Try to dump the type of screenWidth in the text file instead of guessing (i.e. write `typeof screenWidth` into it).

Comment: Good idea - I'll add the results under the main question, though summarised the browser returned typeof = number and the bot returned nothing at all!

Comment: WTF? `typeof` should always return something, even if it's `null` or `undefined`. Something is severely broken there.

Comment: I know - hence the question here. I had even wondered if headless clients/bots didn't create a screen object? But my test for that (as above) didn't work either. It's got me very confused, and I really don't want to have to start agent sniffing bots as life is too short! :)

Comment: Which is why I'm asking you to give us all the JavaScript and PHP code that you use to get the screen width.

Comment: That is all the code that gets the screen width - http://browsertrend.info/js/bti.js

Comment: And the same PHP doesn't change when writing the text file, which is the problem the condition is supposed to solve.

Comment: I'm thinking, I might just add the screen width to the end of the .js call as part of a query string and use .htaccess to serve up a different file if the query string is empty...

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I do not have that much experience with Google Bots, too little info for me to know to help.

But, this [article](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/51478/screen-resolution-of-googlebot-mobile) might be handy

Also, I'd like to suggest, instead of writing 2 conditional statements, you can simply write:

```
if (screenWidth) { ... }
```

Try it out in your browsers console and compare to what you had and see try the truth test; set

```
screenWidth='';
if (!screenWidth) { alert('empty string fails truth test') }

screen=null;
if (!screenWidth) { alert('null fails truth test') }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by write one conditional statement? I'm only using one, just with an else clause.

As for testing the results in my console, won't that just show me what my computer (which is not a bot; that I know of) returns.

Basically I just want to know what the googlebot returns for screen.width - it looks like it is empty but my check against that failed; as did null...

Comment: Additionally, I read that post/article before posting. Not really what I need, but I can see why you posted it - at first glance I thought it would help too :)

Comment: `if (screenWidth)` is not the same as `if (screenWidth >= 1)` unless you already know that `screenWidth` is a number and is non-negative. Otherwise it will succeed with any truthy value--which includes a lot of other kinds of data besides numbers as well as negative numbers.

Comment: Ahh, okay - however, I just tried that and it still always fires the first condition.

Answer (score 0):

Because screen always returns your computer screen size, no matter what your client size is.

Comment: Yup - this is run on a web site that gets traffic from googlebot, not my 'client'. I just need some insight as to why my conditional statement is failing when the value looks like it is obviously empty...